# Certificate verification failed while docker installation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to install docker ce in ubuntu 18.04 which is behind proxy. I have added the gpg key, and in my sourcs.list file the docker entry looks like this :

```
deb [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] http://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
deb-src [arch=amd64 trusted=yes] http://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
```

I had installed the key by first downloading in another system and then moving to current system and then apt-key add.

On running sudo apt-get update I am getting error :

```
 Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/stable/source/Sources  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: xx.xx.xx.xx xxxx] (proxy address)
```